# Can't save query statement as a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know why the following code is working in a SQL Server query, but it can't be saved as a view (I get an error around the where statement when trying to save it).

The content of the source table is very simple:
I have two columns, one called SCP, and one called addressee. For each SCP there might be one or more addressees, and my aim is to get a tabular result where for each SCP you have all the related addressees concatenated in one record.

Could someone indicate where the problem is?
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT SCP
      ,Grouped_Address = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + [addressee] 
                                FROM [test].[dbo].[addressees] AS p2
                                WHERE p2.SCP = p.SCP 
                                FOR XML PATH(N'')
                               ,TYPE
                               ).value(N'.[1]'
                                      ,N'nvarchar(max)'
                                      )
                              ,1
                              ,2
                              ,N''
                              )
FROM [dbo].[addressees] AS p
GROUP BY [SCP]
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: "Error in WHERE clause near '('.
Unable to parse query text."

Comment: You need to also show the compete, exact, statement where you attempt to create a view.

Comment: That query parses fine for me. There's something you aren't telling us. That error ("Error in WHERE clause near '('. Unable to parse query text.") doesn't look like a T-SQL error either.

Comment: Ok, even more confusing: it seems like if I save the view despite of the error, the view is working anyway.

Comment: The code above is the complete content of the view. I'm trying to save it in the MS SQL Server management studio View editor (the GUI).

Comment: Don't use the designer; it's flawed and flaky and can't cope with anything even slightly "complex" (in this case likely the subquery with a `FOR XML PATH`). Stick to doing things properly by writing the T-SQL.

Comment: Use t-sql `create view ViewName as {your query}`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, passing everything via SQL worked. I thought the designer was more trustworthy.

Comment: Incidentally `.value(N'text()[1]'` performs better than `.value(N'.[1]'`